# Why does this code work even though the object is not defined in the javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html

I was using JSLint and it is saying: ***'matte_canvas' is not defined.*** Obviously, in my javascript code I don't have 'matte_canvas' defined, however, it does output the canvas element in the console.

Here is the code I have:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="matte_canvas" width="50" height="50" style="background-color:blue;"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
console.log(matte_canvas);
```

Here it is on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/allisonc/rqo5a417/

Can someone please explain to me how it is working?

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea what to even search for.

Answer (score 2):

`id`s are also globals (if no other value was assigned to them). **Don't rely on this.**
This also works for the `name` attribute on certain elements: `a`, `applet`, `area`, `embed`, `form`, `frameset`, `img`, and `object`.

```
alert(window.matte_canvas);
```

More info: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: I didn't know that. I plan to fix my code, I was just curious why it was working.